# Special characters in search url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a search form for my website with search engine friendly urls.

I have the following form code on every page of my website :

```
<form class="form" method="get" id="searchform" action="searchrd">
Search
```

Here is also my htaccess file :`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^searchrd/?$ /musique/%1.html? [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^/?musique/([^&]+).html?$ musique.php?query=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My problem is the following :

When a user searches for a query with a slash or & for example it gives me a 404 error. I want the slash and & to be removed in order to have a workign search. How can I solve this problem? I think it might be related to regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `[B]` flag

```
RewriteRule ^/?musique/([^&]+).html?$ musique.php?query=$1 [NC,L,QSA,B]
```

> The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric
>   characters before applying the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't work. It still gives me 404 error.